# How can I get the real size of the screen on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, swing, ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I developed a  auto-hide toolbar in Windows. 
Basically this toolbar appear on the screen when the mouse is moved to the right corner of the screen.
Now I'm trying to run the same program on Ubuntu 12.10 but the bar is switching between the 4 screens of Unity.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** Use `Toolkit` to get the **Screen width and height**

**Eg:**

```
Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension dim = tool.getScreenSize();
int screenWidth = dim.width;
int screenHeight = dim.height;
```

Comment: Right. Now I see that the windows I simply modified the position of the frame leaving it almost entirely off-screen. If you do that in Ubuntu the frame is played to another screen ...